# Copy Multiple Excel Tables to VBA Dictionary

Tags: vba, excel

I have  a number of Excel tables that I want to populate into VBA dictionaries. Most of the code is repetitive but there are some unique things for each table that prevent me from making one general purpose routine and calling it for each table. The basic code:

```
Public Sub MakeDictionary( _
    ByVal Tbl As ListObject, _
    ByRef Dict As Scripting.Dictionary)

    ' This routine loads an Excel table into a VBA dictionary

    Dim ThisList As TableHandler
    Set ThisList = New TableHandler

    Dim Ary As Variant

    If ThisList.TryReadTable(Tbl, False, Ary) Then
        Set Dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

        pInitialized = True

        Dim I As Long
        For I = 2 To UBound(Ary, 1)
            Dim ThisClass As MyClass
            Set ThisClass = New MyClass

            ThisClass.Field1 = Ary(I, 1)
            ThisClass.Field2 = Ary(I, 2)

            If Dict.Exists(Ary(I, 1)) Then
                MsgBox "Entry already exists: " & Ary(I, 1)
            Else
                Dict.Add Ary(I, 1), MyClass
            End If

        Next I

    Else
        MsgBox "Error while reading Table"
    End If

End Sub
```

TableHandler and TryReadTable are a class and function that reads a table into a variant array.
Field1 and Field 2 are the columns of the Excel table. My tables range from 1 to 8 columns depending on the table.

I don't know how to make these lines generic:

```
            Dim ThisClass As MyClass
            Set ThisClass = New MyClass

            ThisClass.Field1 = Ary(I, 1)
            ThisClass.Field2 = Ary(I, 2)
```

At this point I have to make 10-12 versions of MakeDictionary where only the class name and class fields are unique. If that's the best way to do it, I can live with it, but, I'd like to make my code more general.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `TableHandler` and `TryReadTable`? Perhaps this code is helping confuse the issue.

Comment: Does this compile and run? I would guess not!

Comment: What is `MyClass`?

Comment: Missing some context - how is this called? Understanding the code around the call may provide insight how to make it generic.

Comment: How do you define each Class type, how do you know which one to use? And, seeing as you don't do anything other than Field1 and Field2, does it really matter?

Answer (score 3):

### Option Explicit!

Suggestion #1: Put `Option Explicit` at the top of the module. **Always!**

This would have prevented the very embarrassing error of `Dict.Add Ary(I, 1), MyClass`. Upon which I see that this code would neither compile nor run unless this Class is a default instance.

### Function or Sub?

If you are only returning one value, then you can use a `Function`, not a `Sub`.

### Keep it Simple!

You have made this more complicated than required. You already pass in a `ListObject`, and you want the `DataRange`. Just do that instead of calling custom classes that return something that you then have to modify/clean up.

> ```
> Dim ThisList As TableHandler
> Set ThisList = New TableHandler
>
> Dim Ary As Variant
>
> If ThisList.TryReadTable(Tbl, False, Ary) Then
>     [...]
> ```

becomes

```
Dim Ary As Variant
If Not Tbl is Nothing then 
    Ary = Tbl.DataRange
    [...]
```

In addition, you have `pInitialized = True` but you don't declare or use `pInitialized` anywhere else.

### Interface or encapsulate?

This is a classic example where the use of an interface would greatly assist.
Create an interface class which basically sets up a contract for some of the methods to be used. In other words, make sure that all of these 10-12 Classes you mention have the right method or property so that you can call and create as required.

> ```
> Public Sub MakeDictionary( _
>     ByVal Tbl As ListObject, _
>     ByRef Dict As Scripting.Dictionary)
> ```

Can become

```
Public Sub MakeDictionary( _
    ByVal Tbl As ListObject, _
    ByRef Dict As Scripting.Dictionary, 
    ByVal SomeTag as <whatever type is most appropriate>)
```

And further in the code you can have

```
    For I = LBound(Ary, 1) To UBound(Ary, 1) '<- remember - we fixed this in my comment above!
        Dim ThisClass As IClass
        Select Case SomeTage
            Case TagA
                Set ThisClass = New MyClass1
            Case TagB
                Set ThisClass = New MyClass2
        End Select

        'ThisClass.Field1 = Ary(I, 1)
        'ThisClass.Field2 = Ary(I, 2)
        ThisClass.RelevantFillMethod(Ary(I, 1),Ary(I, 2))

        If Dict.Exists(Ary(I, 1)) Then ' Just in case there is some sort of transform?
            MsgBox "Entry already exists: " & Ary(I, 1)
        Else
            Dict.Add Ary(I, 1), ThisClass 
        End If
    Next I
```

Now, if the Interface had a factory method which created a new version of the relevant class - you could dispense with the `Dim` and pass the `MyClass1` instance as a parameter, calling `MyClass1.New` as necessary.

```
' Class IClass
Option Explicit

Public Function NewMe() As IClass
End Function

Public Sub RelevantFillMethod(val1 As Variant, val2 As Variant)
End Sub
```

And

```
' Class Class1
Option Explicit
Implements IClass


Private p_V1 As Variant
Private P_V2 As String

Public Function EverythingElse()
    '[...]
End Function


Private Function IClass_NewMe() As IClass
    Set IClass_NewMe = New Class1
End Function

Private Sub IClass_RelevantFillMethod(val1 As Variant, val2 As Variant)
    p_V1 = val1
    P_V2 = CStr(val2)
End Sub
```

### Subs and functions!

Of course, you can make this a bit easier by addressing the single responsibility concept and using logical functions. However, in the OP there is not enough information to understand where this logic break is.

```
Identify and loop through tables
    Create array from table '<= can be a function that returns an array - single responsibility
    Identify relevant Class
    Update Dictionary based on array '<= single responsibility, 
        'parameters could be the array, the dictionary and 
        'the instance of the class based on the interface
```

For example

```
Sub UpdateDictionary(ByVal Ary as Variant, ByRef Dict as Dictionary, ThisClass as IClass)    
    For I = LBound(Ary, 1) To UBound(Ary, 1)
        If Dict.Exists(Ary(I, 1)) Then 
            MsgBox "Entry already exists: " & Ary(I, 1)
        Else
            Set ThisClass = ThisClass.NewMe
            ThisClass.RelevantFillMethod(Ary(I, 1),Ary(I, 2))
            Dict.Add Ary(I, 1), ThisClass 
        End If
    Next I
End Sub
```

### Final comments

What I have suggested above may not be the most elegant - but it is a start. Making something generic is about being able to abstract to the relevant layer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to instantiate a new instance of `MyClass` is it already exists  and  I personally don't like declaring variables inside loops.

> ```
>    Dim ThisClass As MyClass
>
>     For I = 2 To UBound(Ary, 1)
>         If Dict.Exists(Ary(I, 1)) Then
>             MsgBox "Entry already exists: " & Ary(I, 1)
>         Else
>             Set ThisClass = New MyClass
>             ThisClass.Field1 = Ary(I, 1)
>             ThisClass.Field2 = Ary(I, 2)
>             Dict.Add Ary(I, 1), MyClass
>         End If
>     Next I
> ```

Comment: But the declarative statement is only there for compiling convenience and not called every loop - thus what you have here is code-equivalent to the original code. Declaring the variable inside the loop tells me that that variable is only used inside the loop.

Comment: I've gone back and forth on this topic myself. I completely agree with the comment made by @AJD in that declaring the variable inside the loop "limits" the scope (but only limits it visually/contextually). In other languages this scope limit is enforced. I will also declare a variable outside the loop as a reminder of the "actual" scope of a variable, just in case I want to use it later. YMMV

Comment: @AJD The reason that I declare my variables outside of the loops is to reduce clutter.  The variable declaration does not tell me anything about what the loop is supposed to be doing.  I'm pretty up in the air about declaring variables at the point of use altogether using VBA.  It makes much more sense to me in languages that allow you to instantiate classes in declarations using constructors.